# C# .DLL Library acts as Type when imported

Tags: c#, vb.net, dll, reference, using

I have made a simple .DLL Library the has one function called Add, this simply takes two parameters and returns the added value. In my other program, When I add the reference with "using AddNumbers;" I cannot just call the Add procedure, instead it is acting like a Type in which I need to create a variable like "AddNumbers myVariable;" and call the procedures like "myVariable.Add(1, 4);"
This has been confusing me as I do not remember having this issue in VB.

Comment: you need to show the code for this.  If the function is Shared/static you can call it without instancing anything, if not the class containing it needs to be instanced.

Comment: VB.NET allows adding methods to the global namespace, you'd use a Module.  It had to, early VB versions could do that.  C# does not allow that, a *static* method requires the class name, an instance method requires an object reference.  VS2015 and C# version 6 will allow it.

Comment: Did you have your VB code in a module?

Comment: @Plutonix I have now made them static and I can call them as  iwanted to, But I still have to call them like "AddNumbers.AddNumbers.Add(1, 2)" even though I still have "using AddNumbers;" just as a note, the namespace and class are called AddNumbers which is why there is two "AddNumbers." when I call the "Add" method

Comment: If you change either the namespace or the class name, you should only need to list the `ClassName.MethodName`. Why you have to list both is that there is an ambiguity between the namespace and the class, so you have to qualify it.

Comment: When we have two things with exactly the same name, one must qualify the namespace name, this applies to java too(and to all languages I think)

Comment: @niceman Even if I make the names different, is there a way for me not th have to specify the class name? So instead of ClassName.MethodName just have MethodName

Comment: You probably really dont want that.  Otherwise a `Foo.Add()` and `Bar.Add()` could not exist in the same Class Lib.  You'd have to build one DLL for each class or mangle the names (`Foo.FooAdd()`)

Comment: Well if you're inside the class you can use the function without the class name but outside it , I doubt there is a way

Answer (score 0):

Non-private Members of a class can only be used when you create an instance of the class. You can declare your method as static, but you still have to call it with the class name `ClassName.Add(1,4)`.